# Search the contents of a SQL file without extracting it from an archive

Tags: windows, windows-10, 7-zip, sql

I have a 128GB `.sql` file that's located in a `.7z` archive.

For reasons of storage space, I can't extract the file.

- Is there any way to search for a specific line within that `.sql` file, without extracting it from the archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the Mac, the
[ArchCommander](https://www.torrentmac.net/archcommander-2-1/)
can do the viewing of single files without unpacking.

Otherwise, unless someone comes up with a utility that does that,
you will need to program your own solution.

[SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress)
is a C# library that is:

> a compression library in pure C# for .NET Standard 2.0, 2.1, .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0 that can unrar, un7zip, unzip, untar unbzip2, ungzip, unlzip with forward-only reading and file random access APIs.

An example that I
[found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61819964/165358)
is :

```
var archive = SevenZipArchive.Open("test.7z");
var firstFile = archive.Entries.First();
var size = firstFile.Size;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(firstFile.OpenEntryStream()))
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

There might exist other libraries for other languages, but I haven't
searched for them.

Comment: Oh, you gave me an idea with that C# library. Thanks! I'll tick accept as an answer if no one comes along with an already available solution for Windows